# How to disable web application in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-mvc

Can you please give me any idea or an example, how to disable the access of a web application in chrome browser.

In my project I am using spring + hibernate. Because of some design issue design is not coming properly in chrome browser but in Mozilla it is coming properly.

So I want to this through programmatically and stop accessing application in chrome browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the best way is: improve your design and make it work in Chrome. otherwise, you'll be able to use JavaScript to check which browser is used, and block it for those you don't "support"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javaScript navigator object we can identify client browser. This navigator object will display the String as below:

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
```

now you have to check this String contains "Chrome" or not to identify client using chrome or not.

for exp:

```
var str=navigator.userAgent;
if(str.indexof('Chrome')>0){
 // true
}else{

 }
```

Comment: why post same answer again ?

Answer (score 3):

following is the UA string for latest chrome, you can simply check for it on the server side ( preferable ) or client side and remove the application from web page when required.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36
```

for JS use `navigator.userAgent` to check the user agent against and remove the element

reference : http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/

Answer (score 0):

one idea is to add a filter to block or redirect chrome browser to an error page by checking if the user-agent is from chrome.